# How to update a file on the master that take effect on all other branches

Tags: git, github

I have a course on github.com and separate the steps into several branches. Today I tried to change a file in the master and tried to have this file updated into all further branches.

I managed to do it locally by doing:

```
git checkout master
git commit -a -m "my file is updated"
git checkout step1
git rebase master
git checkout step2
git rebase master
... (on all my branches)
```

Then when trying to push like this:

```
git push origin
```

I get an error...

Does anyone have an idea? I believe its quite basic.

Comment: *I get an error...*, well what error do you get?

Comment: Hopefully someone can write you a full answer, but it looks to me like you want to 'git cherry-pick' the last commit from master onto each branch, not reset the whole branch to master.

Comment: The likely issue is a merge conflict with a file that you're going to have to resolve.  You *are* rewriting history in a potentially conflicting way, after all...

Comment: *"Does anyone have an idea? I believe its quite basic."* -- I have an idea: read your question and, assuming for a second that you are a Git guru, see if you could answer to it. You described a lot of (more or less useful) steps then, when the most important thing happened, you got tired and bored and just wrote *"I get an error..."*. If you need an answer put more effort into the question and show what error message you received. It's quite basic.

Answer (score 1):

Git rebase doesn't copy commits from one branch to another.  It moves the entire branch so that it is branched from a new location than it was originally.  In the meantime, it doesn't change the branch you are rebasing *to* at all.  The error you got is probably because you are trying to push a master branch that has had its history changed.  In other words, `git rebase` is basically not going to work for what you seem to want to do.

Instead, use `git cherry-pick`.  Git cherry-pick copies one or more commits from one place in commit history to another.  In this case you want to copy the tip of the master branch to each of a few other branches, so here is what you do:

```
git checkout master
git commit -a -m "my file is updated"
git checkout step1
git cherry-pick -x master
git checkout step2
git cherry-pick -x master
... (etc.)
```

The `-x` includes a note in the auto-generated commit message indicating that it was created by cherry-picking and records from where it was cherry-picked.  I think it's a good habit, but you can omit the flag if you don't care.  Note that cherry-picking "master" grabs only the most recent commit on the master branch, which is what it sounds like you wanted.  If you want several commits from master you will have to specify them as a range.

Once you've done all the cherry-picking you will have to push all of the branches, if you want to have them all copied to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error...
>
> Does anyone have an idea? I believe its quite basic

Don't you find it strange to ask help for an error that don't show us!?!
Should we find what is the error to show you that we are genius?

Anyway... i think that your error is telling you that you can't push with a message like:

> To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of git push --help for details.

That's because each time you are using `git rebase` you are creating a new history **and ditching old history**.

When you try to push the new history on the server, you will ditch the same history and loose commit. By default, git prevent you to to it.

In this special case, what you want to do is `git push --force-with-lease`.

And if this is true:

> (on all my branches)

you could even do `git push origin --force-with-lease --all`.

This is "dangerous" command, so the best advice I could give you is to read and understand how git works (understand what is a DAG) before going forward...

Answer (score -1):

many thanks for your answer, I didn't know about git cherry-pick

Finally I made it work with git rebase, however I had to add -f to force my push

git push -f origin master

git push -f origin step1

...